# Cant find file on blueonyx server running apache

Tags: javascript, php, linux, apache

I got apache running on a blueonyx server. There is a piece of code in a php file which looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/folder_name1/folder_name2/file_name.nocache.js"></script>
.....
```

If I load up that page and check the network tab in my browser it loads that `file_name.nocache.js` fine, I can even go to `http://192.168.0.123/folder_name1/folder_name2/file_name.nocache.js` and the browser will display the contents of that file.

But if I ssh onto that server, I can't find that file. Not even that folder or any of those folders.

I have checked `phpinfo()` and it is not `auto_prepend_file` anything other than a file that just contains `putenv("_HTTP_HOST=".@$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);`.

I have tried `find / -name "folder_name1"` with root, no luck either.

I have tried `grep` on the contents in `file_name.nocache.js`, no luck either.

I don't understand how is this possible. Can someone shed a light on me please?

Comment: I don't know anything about blueonyx, [but Michael Stauber does and he answers someone's questions about directory locations here](http://mail.blueonyx.it/pipermail/blueonyx/2016-April/056550.html).

Comment: @ourmandave Thanks for this document. It looks like we can hide a file from browser but still have it visible in ssh/ftp. What am i experiencing is exactly the opposite. I can access it from browser but can't see it in ssh.

Comment: Is there a `/etc/httpd/conf.d/blueonyx.conf` file you can look at?

Comment: @ourmandave Yes, it looks like a htaccess file. What am i looking for there?

Comment: I didn't know if it might have <Directory> or something that would point to the where the file might be.

Comment: @ourmandave Sorry I'm not good at htaccess mods. Is it ok for me to post it here?

Comment: I'm no expert on htaccess stuff. Just thought something might jump out like a directory path. You might have better luck with httpd.conf in /etc/httpd/conf/. Look for a `DocumentRoot` under a `<VirtualHost>`.

Comment: @ourmandave Thanks. You can have the points for answering if you want that. Just copy my answer and i will accept it as the answer so you can get the points :)

Comment: Thx, I don't care about points. I just wanted an answer as much as you did. Someone should start a site called ApacheEnigmaMachine.com. My favorite section would be the daily "It worked on my machine" puzzler.

Answer (score 1):

To whoever run into similar problem, i found out what happened.

It was these 2 lines here that are pulling the invisible file out of no where:

```
./etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:ProxyPassReverse /folder_name1 http://192.168.0.111/folder_name1
./etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:ProxyPass /folder_name1 http://192.168.0.111/folder_name1
```